# Sending mail from the struts 1.2 application

Tags: java, email, jakarta-ee

How can i configure my struts application so that i can send "email" notification ??

Can anyone give me a relevant URL related to it.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26815382/sending-an-email-through-struts-with-java-mail-api) It may help you. It has similar post.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Java Mail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html).

Any Java application can use it to send e-mails.

Comment: Can you giv me a proper code link as an example just as a matter of reference ??

Comment: I don't know what a 'proper code link' is, but you can have a look at the tutorial section which is on the link in the answer, which has plenty of code samples. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-137820.html